# Signing in to Google account on Android Studio 2 emulator hangs

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Whenever I try to sign in to a Google account on the Android Studio 2 emulator (running M API 23 x86, target - Android 6.0 with Google APIs), the sign in screen hangs.  Anyone have the same experience, and have a workaround?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am running into the same issue. The API 23 emulator freezes up when trying to sign in to a Google account. I was able to work around the issue by using an API 21 emulator instead of API 23. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution.